# How to automatically CC a message to specific recipient in exim

Tags: email, exim

I need to make a configuration within exim that would automatically add a CC recipient whenever the message is sent to a specific TO recipient. 
All I could find is how to do this for BCC, but CCing seems to be done differently, I assume somewhere within PREROUTERS section. Would appreciate any help.